# JQuery multiple attributes filter not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some html that looks like this. It's the textbox on a popup window, specifically, Quora's ask question box. http://www.quora.com/

```
<div class="qtext_editor_content qed_content" group="__w2_TrzaBWs_interaction" interactive="true" w2cid="TrzaBWs" id="__w2_TrzaBWs_editor" contenteditable="true" npdkey="h5evmzsf0.cz3gxez1tjn0cnmi">add<br npdkey="h5evn1ub0.l1r3uudq6by8ehfr">This is my text</div>
```

I would like to retrieve "this is my text", but JQuery's multiple attribute filter has been returning literally all the text on the page. I have tried doing

```
$("div[class='qtext_editor_content qed_content'][group$=_interaction]").text()
```

but without good effect.

Thanks!

Comment: This works here: http://jsfiddle.net/LuCqZ/

Comment: you might have to wrap your required text in a separate tag. jquery returns 'addThis is my text' because that is the text contained between the <div> tag.

Answer (score 0):

The string passed to `$("")` `jQuery("")` should be a css selector like

`$("div.qtext_editor_content.qed_content[group=__w2_TrzaBWs_interaction]").text()`

Comment: The issue with this is that on the actual Quora page, it's also returning the question on the background page, not only the text entered in the dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

It has id, why not just use

```
$('#__w2_TrzaBWs_editor').text()
```